# Resize and compress jpeg

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

i seen [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12850/Capturing-the-Desktop-Screen-with-the-Mouse-Cursor) tutorial of capture screen and i did some edit to it and the result is good,

but the resolution of each image is 1366, 768

[image]

and i want it to be like 683, 384

[image]

but all i get is part of the image

[image]

here is my code:

```
private void Display(Bitmap desktop)
{
    if (desktop != null)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1366, 768);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.DrawImage(desktop, Point.Empty);
        }

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        Image myImg = (bmp as Image);
        myImg.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();

        ssWithMouseViewer.Image = myImg;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(pic);
    }
}
```

here is my form:

[image]

i want to store in the datagridview images with resolution of 683, 384 and less qualty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `g.DrawImage(desktop, Point.Empty);` use `g.DrawImage(desktop, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);`

and create bitmap like `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(683, 384);`