# Using ffmpeg with C#

Tags: c#, image, video, ffmpeg

**First:**
well i'm tired of asking the same question, i do know that i can ask about Coding techniques, not just specific problematic points.

**Background:**
my project is to make a Desktop Recorder, i tried `WM Encoder` it works but double click don't work at most cases "ex: can't open My Computer! i have to press Enter!", i made a search and it turned out that WM Encoder is the problem and it's matter of waiting a new version to solve this problem of double click.

**Now:**
this is my previous questions relate to my problem

- [Re size and compress jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193799/resize-and-compress-jpeg)
- [sort files from folder in String[] Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196381/cant-sort-files-from-folder-in-string-array)
- [create a video from a list of JPEG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203639/how-can-i-create-a-video-from-a-list-of-jpeg-files)
- [Combine images into a movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295946/combine-images-into-a-movie)

**So:**
How to save list of images in one video using `ffmpeg` in step by step?
i got this `ffmpeg -f image2 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -r 12 -s WxH foo.avi` but i have no idea how to use it in my project or where i m going to put this code.

Comment: Maybe you could just call ffmpeg on the command line? I'm not really experienced and there are probably better ways but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results

Comment: that will be good for me, but for a user who only need a button to click will be a headache, about that link sound's good i will try it and i'll tell if it do what i expect.

Comment: Oh of course I didn't mean that the user has to execute (or even see) the command line. I was more talking about the way to actually call ffmpeg.  'Typical' windows users should never be confronted with a command line. ;)

Comment: can you make this as answer so i can accept

Comment: Of course. I wasn't sure if this was an answer at all. That's why I posted it in a comment. Hold on a sec.. Edit: My answer is to trivial and gets converted into a comment. Just gimme an upvote on the comment. You can mark the question as answered yourself tomorrow I guess.